# Не запускается код. В чем проблема?

Tags: c++, eclipse

Linux eclipse c++ Код вроде как скомпилировался, но при нажатии кнопки запустить ничего не происходит. Что я делаю не так и как исправить? (должен выводиться результат в консоль).

```
//intvars.cpp
// работа с переменными целого типа
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int var1;                  // описание переменной var1
  int var2;                  // описание переменной var2
  var1 = 20;                 // присвоение значения переменной var1
  var2 = var1 + 10;          // присвоение значения переменной var2
  cout << "var1+10 равно ";  // вывод строки
  cout << var2 << endl;      // вывод значения переменной var2
  return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На скрине вкладка problems а не консоль

Comment: Сама программа ок, скорее всего проблемы с компилятором или настройками системы.

Comment: Консоль пустая при запуске. Ничего не происходит.